# Prevent Duplicates From The CP

Tags: channel-entries

Is it possible to prevent duplicate entries from being entered in?  Ttrying to see how to prevent a duplicate from the CP.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of in the CPanel is as follows is located at: 
Admin ‣ Security and Privacy ‣ Security and Sessions > denial of duplicate data

However this is mainly for comments and spam protection. I don't believe there is a CPanel setting that denies duplicate channels to be submitted.

Comment: Thank you. Having that setting would be great but looks like for now I need to go another direction. Unless there is a add-on that I have not come across.

Comment: Well hopefully i was able to answer your question.

Comment: In part yes, but it only verifies what I already knew.